# No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-widget, android-appcompat

I know many others have experienced a similar issue and I found these questions that were very similar to my issue:

[Android Support Library v7: Error retrieving parent for item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964902/android-support-library-v7-error-retrieving-parent-for-item)

[error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063552/error-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-give?rq=1)

The problem is that I tried the different solutions offered in those answers such as changing the target sdk to something like 14 or 15, and also cleaning and rebuilding the project. I am using intelij and I havent been able to make the following errors disappear:

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton'

are there any other things that I can try to attempt to correct these errors? any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not including the support library to your project.

Also have a look at this question [Use AppCompat Library for ActionBar support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432314/use-appcompat-library-for-actionbar-support)

Answer (score 0):

Add the support library from your adt location like this :

```
adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat
```

to your project and clean the project..It should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself the following question "Do I want to support older (<4) android versions?"

If you don't want to, you don't have to use AppCompat. If you do want to support older versions, you simply include the Appcombat library.

Right click on your Hierarchy and select import. Browse to the location of your SDK/Extras/Android/Support/V7/Appcompat/ and import that library.

Now mark the project as a library and add the Library to your app. Now, Appcompat can actually be resolved.